# Shows pdf before alert() using JS

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, fpdf

I wanted to show my PDF file when submit button is clicked, but alert() comes first and pdf never loads.

I used onsubmit in my form in html too, so when submit is click the onsubmit comes first, then the alert() message.

I want these steps to take place:

onsubmit --> pdf file loaded --> alert()

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', "", 'catering_info');

        $main = $_GET['main'];
        $last= $_GET['last'];
        $first = $_GET['first'];
        $middle = $_GET['middle'];

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($last) && !empty($first) && !empty($middle) && !empty($street) && !empty($brgy) && !empty($town) && !empty($prov) && !empty($mobile) && !empty($email) && !empty($event) && !empty($venue) && !empty($number)) {

    //--- sending to database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO client_info (ref_no, last_name, first_name, middle_name) VALUES('$main','$last','$first','$middle')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo"REQUEST DENIED";
        }
        else
        {
        echo"<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Successfully Sent to Admin, you will now be proceeded back to Home Page!'); window.location.href='long_page.html';  </script>";
        }


            require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
            $pdf= new FPDF();
            $pdf->Addpage();
            $pdf->SetFont('Times',"", 10);
            $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Reservation Form",1,1, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(40,5, "Reference ID:", 0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(40,5, "$main ,", 0,1);
            $pdf->Cell(40,5, "Name:", 0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(40,5, "$last  ,", 0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(40,5, "$first ", 0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(40,5, "$middle", 0,1);
            $pdf->output("PDF_RESERVATIONS/" . $last . "-" . $first .".pdf", 'F');

    }   
}
```

?>

If you guys know a better way, please help. Anyway I'm trying to use PHP x JS only so as much as possible its PHP or JS... Thanks.

Comment: Divide it into two pages.